# An interval becomes shorter and shorter after each click

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Each time the button below is clicked the interval of 900 ms becomes shorter and shorter.

How to avoid this?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
 $('#mark').show();
 setInterval(function(){$('#mark').hide();}, 900);
});
```

```css
.mark{
display:none;
font-size:3rem;
color:lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<div class='mark' id='mark'>000</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#mark').show();
  console.log('show');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#mark').hide();
    console.log('hide');
  }, 900);
});
```

```css
.mark {
  display: none;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<div class='mark' id='mark'>000</div>
```

Comment: @qadenza glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`

Actually `setInterval()` will execute the code forever, until you clear it.
forExample, in your code, the text will be displayed after every 900ms.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
 $('#mark').show();
 setTimeout(function(){$('#mark').hide();}, 900);
});
```

```css
.mark{
display:none;
font-size:3rem;
color:lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<div class='mark' id='mark'>000</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the interval if its already running on next click otherwise, it will execute after your show function and will lead to a false conclusion that the interval is becoming shorter.

Also it seems like, you don't need setInterval, but setTimeout since you only need to hide the digits once after showing them

```js
let timer = null;
$('button').on('click', function(){
  if(timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
 $('#mark').show();
 timer = setTimeout(function(){$('#mark').hide();}, 900);
});
```

```css
.mark{
display:none;
font-size:3rem;
color:lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<div class='mark' id='mark'>000</div>
```